# How to alter the HTML of the value attribute for an input box?

Tags: jquery, input

What I want to be able to do is alter the "value=" of an input text box using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery).  The ultimate goal is to grab a form using .html() so I have all of the code, along with the values typed into the input boxes.

As an example I have this:

```
<span id="example">
<input type="text" value="" id="rate" />
</span>
```

If a user types into the input box I can save the data using .val, but what I want to do is grab the HTML so I can re-display the input box with the value.

If an user types "bob" into the input.  Then I use:

```
var test = $('#example').html();
```

The variable 'test' holds the following:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="rate" />
```

What I want is:

```
<input type="text" value="bob" id="rate" />
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Phoenix has your answer and you should check out the selectors that are available for forms: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388893/jquery-html-in-firefox-uses-innerhtml-ignores-dom-changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ultimate goal is to grab a form using .html() so I have all of the code, along with the values typed into the input boxes.

You are on to a loser with this strategy. Form values are a separate layer of data which is stored apart from HTML attributes. The HTML `value` attribute is reflected in the `defaultValue` property of the object, *not* the `value` property.

Setting the value or checked/selectedness of a form control does not change the HTML DOM attributes; consequently serialising a form using `innerHTML` or `html()` will not give you form values — except in IE, due to a bug.

(And there are other bugs in IE regarding serialising forms with changed names. Just avoid using serialisation; remembering the values themselves from `value` or `val()` is much more reliable.)

Comment: I agree on the strategy being wrong on this. I'll come up with another way, so much for the easy way :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this question a duplicate of: [SO138893: jQuery html() in firefox (uses .innerHTML) ignores DOM changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388893/jquery-html-in-firefox-uses-innerhtml-ignores-dom-changes).  The answer there should solve your problem.  I don't think this newer question should get deleted though - it might help someone else find their way to the other one.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't even know this issue even existed...
And for actually reading the OP question... :)

Comment: I didn't realize this was confined to a browser issue.  The other question didn't even come up when I searched before asking.

Answer (score 0):

To alter the value of an input element with id rate you can use this.

```
$("#rate").val(newvalue);
```

To set the value to bob use

```
$("#rate").val("bob");
```

Comment: Although I'm realizing now that you might be on a browser other than Firefox (which displays this bug) - This doesn't solve the problem at all: http://jsbin.com/uniko

Answer (score 0):

I have check your code and it is working fine. The only thing which is missing is the type of the input filed. You can try the following things

```
$('#example')[0].innerHTML
```

And Second one is the

```
$("#rate")[0].outerHTML
```

Hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

How about not saving the actual HTML, but saving the attributes?

```
var attr = {
'value' : $('#rate').val(),
'type' : $('#rate').attr('type') }
//later on in the code or something:
var inp = $('<input />').attr('id', 'rate').attr(attr);
```