# jquery and input text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would know if this is a bug... When I alert html content from #test, I get :

```
<input name="sum" value="" type="text">
```

whereas it was set to 55 just before the alert, and I can view it on the brower.

Can you tell me why ? :-)

```
    <div id="test">
    <input type="text" name="sum" value="">
</div>

<script language="javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").find("input[name='sum']").val(55);
    alert($("#test").html());
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Tom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug. The value of #test is not part of the HTML content of the input -- it was set after the element was inserted into the DOM -- and thus the html() function doesn't return it.

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought that html() function would change according to updates from children...

Comment: If you'd added more elements (for instance) inside the div, html() would return them, but changing attribute values is not reflected. I think.

Comment: Is there a way to see how the source looks really like ?

Thanks !

Comment: That's kind of a tricky question. Arguably, the source of the page doesn't include the value that you've set later. But to answer your question more helpfully, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388893/jquery-html-in-firefox-uses-innerhtml-ignores-dom-changes is another discussion of this issue, which provides a jQuery plugin you could use.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript doesn't change the physical markup on the page. It changes the DOM. The DOM is constructed from the markup, but after that the markup isn't crucial.

<strike>You don't want to alert the `HTML`, you want to alert the value of the input:</strike>

```
alert($("#test :input[name='sum']").val());
```