# JQuery html() call doesn't return value after forcing attr update

Tags: jquery, firefox, dom

Maybe I'm not understanding something basic here, but the html() call doesn't return an element with all attributes filled in, even after an explicit call to set the attribute.

For example, I have a text box:

```
<input type="text" id="foo" value="" />
```

When the user fills in a value in this box, a function is called (onBlur of input text box).

```
$('#foo').blur(function(event) { updateFoo(this); });
```

In that function the following code exists:

```
function updateFoo(input) {
  // force DOM update??
  $('#'+input.id).attr('value', input.value);

  // successfully displays value user entered
  alert($('#'+input.id).attr('value')); 

  // displays input element, with value not filled in,
  // like: 'input type="text" id="foo" value="" />'
  alert($('#'+input.id).parent().html()); 

  ...
}
```

Shouldn't the html() call return the element with the value attribute set?

I'm using Firefox 3.6.13 on Max OSX.

I saw this forum post: http://forums.asp.net/t/1578929.aspx
which I based some of my assumptions off of...

Thanks,
Galen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After researching some more, I ran across this post:

[jQuery html() in Firefox (uses .innerHTML) ignores DOM changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388893/jquery-html-in-firefox-uses-innerhtml-ignores-dom-changes)

which pretty much sums up the problem I'm having.  Basically it's a firefox implementation issue...

Instead of:

```
$('#'+input.id).attr('value', input.value);
```

I'm now using:

```
input.setAttribute('value', input.value); // force DOM update
```

which solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a side effect of the fact that `value` has a very specialized use.  I imagine that the value is stored in some local property instead of in the DOM itself.

If you change the `attr` to something else, like `newattr`, it works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/m9vWT/

Of course, that doesn't help with the `value` attribute...

Comment: thanks for your response.  Yes, it seems like new attributes get updated fine.  I solved the problem in another way (see my answer in this post)