# JQuery issue with firefox: $('#element_id').html() not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

`<div id="element_id">hellow world</div>`

```
var value = $('#element_id').html()
```

returns the `"hello world"` sometimes, but not always. `val()` always works, but not `html()` This only happens in firefox (always works in Chrome). Any ideas?

**EDIT** 
Still haven't figured out the problem yet, but I will post the conclusion once I have found it! Thanks for the responses.

Comment: What does it return the other times, a empty string?

Comment: check if there is another element with the same ID in the document. Otherwise it should always return the html.

Comment: There are none. What's weird is really that most of the times it works.

Comment: Check if some add-in conflicts with the javascript. Try to turn off all the add-in you have, and try again.

Comment: Might be hitting a dead end, but created http://jsfiddle.net/75MCh/ can you reproduce the issue ?

Comment: Where are you calling this? Straight in the <script> tag? Some context would really help...

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388893/jquery-html-in-firefox-uses-innerhtml-ignores-dom-changes) previous question might help you.

P.S. When you say it is sometime working and sometime not working, are there some changes going on the div's content ?

Comment: no, the div content doesn't change. It is loaded from a saved cookie each time.

Comment: then you might have problems dealing with cookies rather than with than .html() function itself, for instance - user can have cookies disabled or performed a cleanup of their cookies recently

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping it into a timeout...

```
function sayHello() {
  var someContent = $('#element_id').html();
  alert(someContent);
}

setTimeout('sayHello()', 500);
```

See if it's getting the content far too early?

Answer (score 0):

This worked using jQuery 1.4.4. I haven`t tested with other versions.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function showhtml() {
            var eid = $('div.eid').html();
            alert(eid);
            $('code.status').html(eid);
        }
        showhtml();
    });
```

Remembering that .text will return only the text inside the div and .html will return the text surrounded by the html tags.

Answer (score 0):

The complete unaltered code for you to try:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            p {color:#4f4}
            code {color:#999;font-family:monospace;font-size:14px}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                function showhtml(n) {
                    //1 for html 0 for text
                    if(n == 1) {
                        var eid = $('div.eid').html();
                        alert(eid);
                        $('code.status').html(eid);
                    } else if(n == 0 || n == null) {
                        var eid = $('div.eid').text();
                        alert(eid);
                        $('code.status').text(eid);
                    }
                }
                showhtml();
            });
        </script>
        <title>jQuery html() text()</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="eid">
            <p>1 ajfdlk jaldkfjdksljfkldjlfkjal;fd</p>
            <em>2 ajd;fjal;kdjf</em>
        </div>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <code class="status"></code>
    </body>
</html>
```