# why doesn't innerHTML reflect changes made in an html form?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

this is a part of my html file:

```
<form id="foo">
   <select>
      <option value="1" selected>1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Now when I use the following javascript code, it gives me the exact content of the form:

```
alert(getElementById("foo").innerHTML);
```

However, after I change my options withing the form, the above code still returns the previous version of the form's content.

For instance, let's say I've switch my option from "1" to "2". In this case I expect the above javascript code returns the form's content with option "2" selected; but no matter how I change the form, it always return the original version of the form's content.

Comment: possible duplicate :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696453/dynamically-modified-value-of-input-not-reflected-in-dom

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Content attributes show the initial state.

IDL attributes (aka properties) show the current state.

For example, let's say we have a text input like this:

```html
<input value="foo" />
```

It's default text is "foo". Let's change it to "bar". Then,

- `input.getAttribute('value')` will be the initial value: `"foo"`.
- `input.defaultValue` will be equivalent to the above: `"foo"`.
- `input.value` will be the current value: `"bar`.

```js
var inp = document.querySelector('input');
(inp.oninput = function() {
  document.getElementById('attr').textContent = inp.getAttribute('value');
  document.getElementById('defVal').textContent = inp.defaultValue;
  document.getElementById('val').textContent = inp.value;
})();
```

```html
<input value="foo" />
<p>Attribute: <span id="attr"></span></p>
<p>Default value: <span id="defVal"></span></p>
<p>Value: <span id="val"></span></p>
```

In your case it happens something similar. `innerHTML` only shows the HTML markup, which includes content attributes (which reflect the initial state) but not IDL attributes (current state).

If you want the current state, read it with IDL attributes instead of using `innerHTML`.

Comment: what you said seems to be correct only in case of elements with 'value' attribute (i.e. text boxes, buttons, ...). But the problem is that neither <select> nor <option> have such attribute as 'value'. If I'm wrong and you still think there's a workaround, would you include a simple example like mine above this page?

Comment: In your case it's the same with `selected` instead of `value`, but it's more complicated because there are multiple `option`s. The workaround depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve. But you can try iterating the options and us`setAttribute` or `removeAttribute` depending on if they are selected or not. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0trmz1oe/)

Answer (score 3):

This is snippet from the Mozilla Developer Network page for `innerHTML`.

More details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

> This property was initially implemented by web browsers, then
>   specified by the WHATWG and W3C in HTML5. Old implementations may not
>   all implement it exactly the same way. For example, when text is
>   entered into a text input, **Internet Explorer changes the value
>   attribute of the input's innerHTML property but Gecko browsers do not.**

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$('myselect').find('option').prop('selected', false).eq(1).prop('selected', true);
```

In other words, it sets the 'selected' property the way you want it in *all* options.

Comment: OP might not have jQuery