# difference between setAttribute and htmlElement.attribute='value'

Tags: javascript, setattribute

what would be the difference between the two ,

```
b1.setAttribute('id','b1');
```

and

```
b1.id='b1';
```

is one of them more efficient than the other ? and do both of them will do exactly the same task ? and will they be different in some situations ?

Comment: More important to understand the different effect that it may have, which depends on the attribute being set. In the vast majority of cases, it's better (simpler and more consistently supported) to set the property directly, unless you have a particular reason to set the attribute (and can deal with the various quirks associated with doing that).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> difference between setAttribute and htmlElement.attribute='value'

That latter bit, `htmlElement.attribute='value'`, isn't quite accurate. You're not setting an *attribute* there, you're setting a property.

DOM element instances in memory have various properties, *some* of which connect to or relate to attributes and others which don't.

*Attributes*, on the other hand, are name/value pairs that are read directy from the HTML markup (and if you serialize a DOM element, for instance by accessing its `innerHTML` property, are written to the markup you get back).

When the property and attribute are related/linked in some way, the property is called a *reflected property* (of the attribute). Sometimes, the reflected property's name isn't quite the same as the attribute's name (`class` becomes `className`, `for` becomes `htmlFor`), and sometimes the link between them isn't 1:1.

So for instance, `id` is a reflected property of the `id` attribute. But select boxes have a `selectedIndex` property for which there's no attribute.

> do both of them will do exactly the same task ?
>
> and will they be different in some situations ?

It depends on the attribute/property:

- `id` and several others are *directly* reflected: Setting the `id` property and setting the `id` attribute do exactly the same thing. Offhand, this is also true of the `htmlFor` property / `for` attribute (except on old IE which has bugs in `setAttribute` there), the `rel` property/attribute, the `className` / `class` attribute (except on old IE which has bugs in `setAttribute` there), the `name` attribute on form fields and some other elements, the `method` and `action` properties/attributes on forms, and several others.
- The `value` property, on the other hand, doesn't set the `value` attribute *at all*. It just gets its default value from it. On most browsers ("all" at this point?), there's a separate `defaultValue` property which *does* directly reflect the `value` attribute.
- The `href` property is slightly different from the `href` attribute in relation to relative vs. absolute links. The attribute can contain a relative path, and using `str = elm.getAttribute("href")` gives you that relative path; if you read the *property* (`str = elm.href`), it will always be an absolute path (e.g., the resolved path). Setting the `href` property to a relative path sets the attribute to that path, but again reading teh `href` property will give you the absolute (resolved) version. Setting the `href` property to an absolute path will set the attribute to that absolute path.
- There are several boolean properties which are represented as booleans (true/false), but since attribute values are always strings, the attribute is either *not there* for false (`getAttribute` returns `null`) or there for true. If it's there, it must have the value `""` or the same as its name (e.g., `multiple="multiple"`, case-insensitive), although in practice browsers treat any present attribute as `true` regardless of its actual content.
- Several properties aren't reflected in attributes at all, so setting them doesn't set/change any attribute.

> is one of them more efficient than the other ?

It's never going to make a big enough difference to care, so it doesn't matter. It also probably varies dramatically by browser.

Comment: I think the downvoter ment `If it's there, it must have the value "" or the same as its name (e.g., multiple="multiple", case-insensitive)"`. This is true, though, according to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6961821/2827823, it obviously get interpreted slightly different based on if it is XHTML or HTML5.

Comment: @LGSon: That sentence wasn't there when the answer was downvoted. :-) In any case, that relates to markup, not the value the attribute can have when you interact with it via JavaScript. The downvote could have been because someone thought the answer lacked detail, or it could be one of a string of random downvotes I've been getting the last several days (including another contemporaneous with this one, on an answer from years ago).