# jquery .html() function issue

Tags: jquery, html

If i have a Textarea inside div. Something like

```
   <div id="section3">
    <textarea id="txtArea1">old value
    </textarea>
   </div>
```

And by using:

```
alert($('#section3').html());
$('#txtArea1').val('new value');
alert($('#section3').html());
```

both alerts show the same markup with ("old value");
is there any way i can flush the html so the last statement gets the updated html markup?

Comment: Is your code sample correct? Looks like it should say `$('#txtArea1').val('new value');`.

Comment: sorry about the wrong id. But that's not my issue. I just wrote it wrong. That's not actualy my code it's a simplified version. But even with txtArea1 i have the same html() result.

Comment: At first, I thought you were having problems with the last alert showing html tags instead of just text. Now I'm just confused.

Comment: Use `.html()` instead of `.val()` to change the textarea contents.

Comment: This may be a browser specific issure; are you using Firefox? If so se this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388893/jquery-html-in-firefox-uses-innerhtml-ignores-dom-changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably a browser specific issue. You can test it out using [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wMwX6/).
The above code fails in Firefox but works in IE. [See this stackoverflow question and answer for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388893/jquery-html-in-firefox-uses-innerhtml-ignores-dom-changes).

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#txtArea1").html("new value");
alert($("#txtArea1").html());
```

Comment: It was a browser specific issue in the end. But your answer did help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) with textareas and jQuery. It's slightly counter-intuitive seeing as the textarea content is *inside* the tags, as opposed to being a `value=""`, but it's how it's done by jQuery to keep consistency.

```
alert($('#section3').val());

$('#textarea').val('new value');

alert($('#section3').val());
```

Will give you the new value.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

`alert( $('section3').text() );`

make that your last line.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have textarea with id "textarea". try to change

```
$('#textarea').val('new value');
```

to

```
$('#txtArea1').val('new value');
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
 $('#txtArea1').val('new value');
```

To:

```
 $('#txtArea1').text('new value');
```