# Using jQuery to clone form elements with dynamically added values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that is similar to this:

```
<fieldset id="user">
  <input type="text" id="firstName">
  <input type="text" id="lastName">
</fieldset>
```

Then I do an Ajax call to fill the values of those two fields. At this point I want to save the current state of the form (with the populated values) in case the user needs to revert back after making a change.

I've tried this:

```
$("#user").clone(true).html()
```

As well as this:

```
$("#user").html()
```

both return the original html from the dom that was created before the fields were populated. Is there a way to grab the html with the values after they have been populated with JS?

Comment: possible duplicate for this question:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388893/jquery-html-in-firefox-uses-innerhtml-ignores-dom-changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388893/jquery-html-in-firefox-uses-innerhtml-ignores-dom-changes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in data. Where you do the ajax call, store the value in the data for for the element too:

```
$.data( $("#firstname"), "value", value );
$.data( $("#lastname"), "value", value );
```

At the point you want to revert the change:

```
$("#firstname").val( $.data($("#firstname"), "value") );
$("#lastname").val( $.data($("#lastname"), "value") );
```

When you revert, you can iterate through x-number of elements too

```
$("#user input").each( function() {
   $(this).val( $.data($(this), "value") );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var prev = $('#user').html(); // store previous state

$.ajax({
  url: '',
  ....
  ....
  success: function(res) {
    //assume that your res is like:
    /**
    res = {
        firstname: 'FIRSTNAME', 
        lastname : 'LASTNAME'
    }
    */
    $('#user input#firstname').val(res.firstname);
    $('#user input#lastname').val(res.lastname);
  } 
})

//For revert:

$('#user').empty().html(prev);
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `.` before `val(res.firstname);` and `val(res.last);`? Like that: `$('#user input#firstname').val(res.firstname);
    $('#user input#lastname').val(res.last);`