# include new input values when selecting from the dom using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

The below snippet illustrates the problem, when the user adds some input to the second text input field, the alert does not include the new input.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#click').live('click',function(){ alert($('#test').html())})
  })
</script>

<div id="test">
<input type="text" value="test"/>
<input type="text" value=""/>
</div>

<a id="click">clickme</a>
```

for convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/CqPkP/

Comment: What are you trying to do? The code you posted does what it should. Are you trying to pull out what the users enters? If so you need to grab those with `.val()`.

Comment: lol, no! i'm trying to copy a portion of the dom, with new values, insert it into some html i've retrieved via ajax, then replace the copied portion with the newly wrapped version. perhaps i should have posted that as a question instead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.html()` function will not get the updated DOM attributes. You have to manually get the updated attributes.. check below demo,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/skram/CqPkP/2/

**Full Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#click').live('click', function() {
        alert($('#test').formhtml())
    })
});

(function($) {
    var oldHTML = $.fn.html;

    $.fn.formhtml = function() {
        if (arguments.length) return oldHTML.apply(this, arguments);
        $("input,button", this).each(function() {
            this.setAttribute('value', this.value);
        });
        $("textarea", this).each(function() {
            // updated - thanks Raja!
            this.innerHTML = this.value;
        });
        $("input:radio,input:checkbox", this).each(function() {
            // im not really even sure you need to do this for "checked"
            // but what the heck, better safe than sorry
            if (this.checked) this.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
            else this.removeAttribute('checked');
        });
        $("option", this).each(function() {
            // also not sure, but, better safe...
            if (this.selected) this.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
            else this.removeAttribute('selected');
        });
        return oldHTML.apply(this);
    };

    //optional to override real .html() if you want
    // $.fn.html = $.fn.formhtml;
})(jQuery);
```

**Ref:** [jQuery html() in Firefox (uses .innerHTML) ignores DOM changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388893/jquery-html-in-firefox-uses-innerhtml-ignores-dom-changes)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I understand u correct but try to use val() function to retrieve the value of the textbox.
See mor infos here in the docs http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

When the user enters input into an `input` element, it does not update the HTML of that input. So calling `.html()` on it won't give you the new data that is in the field.

If you want to just get all the values in the input fields, you can do something like this:

```
$('#click').live('click',function(){
  alert($('#test input').map(function() { return this.value; }).get());
});
```

You have to use `map` because calling `val()` will only give you the value of the first `input` element.