# get innerHTML AS HAS BEEN CHANGED

Tags: javascript, jquery

Initially a form might have a field like this:

```
<input type="text" name="Age" value="" />
```

Anyway, you fill it in with a value of 34

Quite simply, I want to store a cached snapshot of the form AS LAST STATE, something like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
document.getElementById('cached').value=document.getElementById('form1').innerHTML;
</script>
```

However, the result I'm getting is just:

```
<input type="text" name="Age" value="" />
```

vs. what I want with the value of 34 in it:

```
<input type="text" name="Age" value="34" />
```

Any way to get the "live" innerHTML?  I would accept a jQuery solution here for sure.  Thanks!

Comment: so this makes no sense

Comment: yeah, you get the innerHTML after it has been changed

Comment: Typing into an _HTMLInputElement_ does not change the _HTML_ of the page.

Comment: The `innerHTML` *doesn't* change. It's the `value` property of the DOM node that changes.

Comment: You will only see changes that causes repainting the layout (add/remove a node/attribute, not at property/attribute change

Comment: the innerHTML of a form with inputs will always show the value attributes with their initial value because the ***value attribute never changes*** (unless you specifically change the attribute with code), instead, the value *property* changes. therefore, the snapshot you obtained IS the current live snapshot of the html.

Comment: The normal way to save the state of a form is to loop through all of its elements and store the individual values (and current checked/selected states) in an array or object.

Comment: And the jQuery way of doing that is `$("#myform").serializeArray();`

Answer (score 0):

even jquery will return the same result . you need to do a bit of trick here .
because when you fill a field you dont really set the value proprietary of html .

```
var snapshot = $('#field_ID').clone();
var ssv = $('#field_ID').val();
var snapshot = snapshot.attr('value' , ssv);
```

now if you use

```
$('body').append(snapshot);
```

you will get the field with the value .

### when to take snapshots

best way to know when to take these snapshots is when the user focuses out of the box

```
$('#field_ID').focusout(function(){
    var snapshot = $(this).clone();
    var ssv = $(this).val();
    var snapshot = snapshot.attr('value' , ssv);
    $('body').append(snapshot);
})
```

Comment: No, you *do* set the value property. That's why viewing the attributes doesn't show the updated value. jQuery is just muddying the issue in this case since `attr()` provides abstraction of the underlying properties.

Comment: @TimMedora however, in current versions .attr() actually does literally set the attribute and doesn't touch the property. if the property changes at the same time, that's the browser's doing.

Comment: @TimMedora i bit you dont :) `value = cdata [CA]
This attribute specifies the initial value of the control. It is optional except when the type attribute has the value "radio" or "checkbox".`

Comment: `value` is just the initial value not what you set

Comment: Yes, that has changed around significantly between jQuery versions. That's why I'm saying jQuery muddies the issue. It's better to look at the direct DOM implementation to understand why you see what you are seeing. I'm not saying that this doesn't solve it; I'm saying that it's useful to know the reason why this occurs.

Comment: @TimMedora that proves exactly what i said , you dont set the attribute it self when you change the value.

Comment: You said "when you fill a field you don't set the value property"...I'm saying that when you type into the form field the value property is set by the browser, but the attribute is not updated.

Comment: potato potatoes ... lol seems like it's so the same in this case .

Answer (score 0):

@all, here is what worked for me:

```
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388893/jquery-html-in-firefox-uses-innerhtml-ignores-dom-changes
(function($) {
  var oldHTML = $.fn.html;

  $.fn.formhtml = function() {
    if (arguments.length) return oldHTML.apply(this,arguments);
    $("input,button", this).each(function() {
      this.setAttribute('value',this.value);
    });
    $("textarea", this).each(function() {
      // updated - thanks Raja & Dr. Fred!
      $(this).text(this.value);
    });
    $("input:radio,input:checkbox", this).each(function() {
      // im not really even sure you need to do this for "checked"
      // but what the heck, better safe than sorry
      if (this.checked) this.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
      else this.removeAttribute('checked');
    });
    $("option", this).each(function() {
      // also not sure, but, better safe...
      if (this.selected) this.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
      else this.removeAttribute('selected');
    });
    return oldHTML.apply(this);
  };

  //optional to override real .html() if you want
  // $.fn.html = $.fn.formhtml;
})(jQuery);
```

this gives me, not the form array, but the "innerHTML" of the form WITH mods to the data at time of submission.  This is a quick and easy way to recreate the form as it was at a given time - a snapshot if you will.  I use this on a multi-step process to allow the user a quick "back" button option that doesn't touch the database or require extensive PHP processing.