# Script loads gif in internet explorer, chrome, but not firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

To properly display a "loading" image in my application, I made the following script:

```
var spinnerVisible = false;

function ShowProgress() {
    if (!spinnerVisible) {
        $('div#layer').fadeIn("fast");
        $('div#spinner').fadeIn("fast");
        spinnerVisible = true;

        var spinner = $('#spinner');

        spinner.html('<span>Loading, please wait...</span><img src="/Content/ajax-loader.gif" width="250" height="250"/>').css('background', '#fff').show();
    }
}
```

The `ajax-loader.gif` image is loading fine in internet explorer and Chrome, but it does not load in Firefox?

*EDIT*

I have obtained the url of the image, which goes like this:

```
http://localhost:63779/Content/ajax-loader.gif
```

If I copy-paste the url in firefox, the gif is loading, but now when the function is called...?

*EDIT 2*

I don't know if it is related, but I have found this:

[jQuery html() in Firefox (uses .innerHTML) ignores DOM changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388893/jquery-html-in-firefox-uses-innerhtml-ignores-dom-changes)<

Maybe it is related to my problem?

*EDIT 3*

Ok, so something strange happened, which I don't really like, but here goes:

Firs I have tried this:

```
    var element = document.getElementById('spinner');

    element.setAttribute("'<span>Loading, please wait...</span><img src=\"/Content/ajax-loader.gif\" width=\"250\" height=\"250\" background=\"#fff\"/>')", element.innerHTML);

    alert(document.getElementById("spinner").innerHTML);
```

As I tested in firefox it gave me an error saying that there were illegal characters in my string. So I put the `element.setAttribute` line in comments and I got the proper alert...
And the gif showed!

But that's not all: sometimes it plays, sometimes it does not. I'm slightly confused right now, I don't understand why.

Comment: checked the console? - What does your function call look like?

Comment: I do now know how to use Firefox's console.

Comment: Hit F12 - this will open Developer Tools in Chrome, Firefox and even IE. After opening them you usually should reload the page.

Comment: Ok, managed to open the console, it remains empty.

Comment: Try to find your image in the DOM/HTML-Inspector and check if it' there and the proper CSS-Styles are applied. However to make it easier for us you could try to create a JS-Fiddle or provide more information in general.

Comment: can you try to insert a console.log in your function to see if it is actually called (at the end of the function)

Comment: Done as you ask @Kaiido and the console.log does log, so the function is called

Comment: For your third edit, there are a few issues : you added one parenthesis that shouldn't be there ; you don't need to add all those anti-slashes (`\"`) if you just get the string between single quotes (`'`) ; and [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) is a property of the DOM element, you should set it like that : `element.innerHTML = '<span>Loading, please wait...</span><img src="/Content/ajax-loader.gif" width="250" height="250" background="#fff"/>';`

Comment: And for your main issue, could you try with a web hosted file (i.e `http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Ajax-loader.gif`)